# Dot product with floats in nested arrays

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I am trying to implement a dot product function using pure, base python (no imports or 3rd-party libraries). For an array of ints, I know I can use the function below:

```
def dot(v1, v2):
    return sum(x*y for x,y in zip(v1,v2))
```

However, my arrays are floats:

```
lista = [[2.62, -3.97], [-2.32, -1.30], [-1.09, -0.45]]
listb = [-0.75, 2.75]
```

and when I try `print(dot(lista, listb))`, I get:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: That's not the problem here at all... the problem is that one of your lists is nested.

Comment: Why are you trying to dot product a two-dimensional array with a one-dimensional one?

Comment: What do you expext for output?

Comment: For output, I was expecting [-12.89, -1.83, -0.42]

Comment: I'd recommend taking a step back and understanding what a dot product is and how it is computed. Any non-trivial dot product between two matrices will need 3 loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to traverse one additional level to perform the multiplications:

```
lista = [[2.62, -3.97], [-2.32, -1.30], [-1.09, -0.45]]
listb = [-0.75, 2.75]
final_results = [sum(a*b for a, b in zip(listb, i)) for i in lista]
```

Output:

```
[-12.8825, -1.8350000000000004, -0.41999999999999993]
```

Or, utilizing a function with `map`:

```
def dot(m, n = [-0.75, 2.75]):
  return sum(a*b for a, b in zip(m, n))

print(list(map(dot, lista)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Since everyone hates my question I'll delete it. But thank you for this!

Comment: @Adam_G No, your question is fine. The users are just pointing out that a true dot-product requires a bit more logic than your original code applies.

Comment: @Adam_G I might suggest rewording the title and part of the question to more accurately reflect what was actually the problem. I suspect some of the downvotes are coming from people who simply left after finding that the question was not in fact about floating-point values at all.

Comment: Ah, thanks! That spate of downvotes was very demoralizing :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're coming from Matlab or a similar language, where things written for one dimension automagically work in higher dimensions. This is because Matlab supports what is called [array-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming). Python does not have this feature, so you have to traverse the array by hand.

```
map(lambda x: dot(x, listb), lista)
```